# Union all in Vertica SQL based on tables with different number of columns?

Tags: sql, union, vertica

Hellow i have two tables in Vertica SQL:

table 1

```
col1  col2  col3
1      3    5
2      4    6
```

table 2

```
col1  col2
11    33
22    44
```

And I would like to UNION these two tables, so as as result I would like to have:

```
col1  col2  col3
1      3     5
2      4     6
11     33    NULL
22     44    NULL
```

How can I do it in vertica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should use `UNION ALL` and define the extra column with whatever default value you want:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from table1
union all
select col1, col2, NULL as col3
from table2;
```

`UNION` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  In general, you should use `UNION ALL` unless you intend to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

use `null` as follows:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from table1
union 
select col1, col2, null from table2
```